# How would PizzaStore accept different factories when depending on SimplePizzaFactory?

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory

When I'm reading factory pattern of Head First Design Patterns, I'm confused when reading the simple factory part. Here is the class diagram. 
[image]

PizzaStore code:

```
 public class PizzaStore {

  SimplePizzaFactory factory;

  public PizzaStore(SimplePizzaFactory factory) {
    this.factory = factory;
  }

  public Pizza orderPizza(String type) {
    Pizza pizza;
    pizza = factory.createPizza(type);
    pizza.prepare();
    pizza.bake();
    pizza.cut();
    pizza.box();
    return pizza;
  }
// other methods here
}
```

code for SimplePizzaFactory

```
public class SimplePizzaFactory {

  public Pizza createPizza(String type) {
    Pizza pizza = null;
    if (type.equals("cheese")) {
      pizza = new CheesePizza();
    } else if (type.equals("pepperoni")) {
      pizza = new PepperoniPizza();
    } else if (type.equals("clam")) {
      pizza = new ClamPizza();
    } else if (type.equals("veggie")) {
      pizza = new VeggiePizza();
    }
    return pizza; 
  }
}
```

in Franchising the pizza store part, it says:

> If we take out SimplePizzaFactory and create three different
>   factories, NYPizzaFactory, ChicagoPizzaFactory and
>   CaliforniaPizzaFactory, then we can just compose the PizzaStore with
>   the appropriate factory and a franchise is good to go.

in code,

```
NYPizzaFactory nyFactory = new NYPizzaFactory();
PizzaStore nyStore = new PizzaStore(nyFactory);
nyStore.order(“Veggie”);

ChicagoPizzaFactory chicagoFactory = new ChicagoPizzaFactory();
PizzaStore chicagoStore = new PizzaStore(chicagoFactory);
chicagoStore.order(“Veggie”);
```

My questions is, PizzaStore has a dependency on a concret class, which is 
SimplePizzaFactory, how can we create a PizzaStore instance with NYPizzaFactory instance or 
ChicagoPizzaFactory instance?

Thanks for all your answers! In response to some answers, in case new answers come in the same way:

- Some mentions AbstractFactory or a PizzaFactory interface. I knew
  that concept, but that concept comes later in the book, as abstract
  factory pattern, after the factory method pattern. So I don't think
  the simple factory means AbstractFactory related concept here .
- NYPizzaFactory and ChicagoPizzaFactory extends
  SimplePizzaFactory,couild be that, but if the authors mean that, I can't see why they concern quailty control, as the following:

> So you test marketed the SimpleFactory idea, and what you found was
>   that the franchises were using your factory to create pizzas, but
>   starting to employ their own home grown procedures for the rest of the
>   process: they’d bake things a little differently, they’d forget to cut
>   the pizza and they’d use third-party boxes. Rethinking the problem a
>   bit, you see that what you’d really like to do is create a framework
>   that ties the store and the pizza creation together, yet still allows
>   things to remain flexible.

Comment: What do you mean by "new a PizzaStore"

Comment: @DevonRutledge Its a class which is defined in the question.

Comment: I know what PizzaStore is. How do you new a class? Does he mean new PizzaStore(); or just create a new one?

Comment: @Devon Rutledge  I mean just that, creating an instance of PizzaStore

Answer (score 1):

You will still have `PizzaStoreFactory` but it should either be an `abstract` class or `interface`, with `NYPizzaFactory` & `ChicagoPizzaFactory` deriving from it.

This allows your `PizzaStore` object to polymorphically create pizzas without knowing which type of factory it's using to make them.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done if `NYPizzaFactory` and `ChicagoPizzaFactory` **extends**`SimplePizzaFactory`.

Another possibility is to create a `PizzaFactory` interface and make `PizzaStore` depend on that. And then all concrete implementations of `PizzaFactory`(`NYPizzaFactory`, `SimplePizzaFactory` etc..) can be passed to `PizzaStore`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept of AbstractFactory, according to what you are asking.

Wherein, in addition to the method where you create pizza based on type passed to the createPizza() function, you also need to first set the required PizzaFactory in prior to creating pizza, using another function.